PHD ULTRA syringe pump communicate with Arduino
I have a PHD ULTRA syringe pump from Harvard Apparatus. I want to establish communication between an Arduino and the syringe pump. The company provided me with a Python code, but Arduino does not support Python. Therefore, I converted this code to C++ to make it compatible with the Arduino. I am using an RS-232 to TTL converter between the Arduino and the syringe pump.
However, when I attempted to use this code to establish communication, I encountered issues. Could someone please help me amend this code if there are any errors? I have attached a diagram of my setup and will also attach the Python code provided by the company.
Note: The syringe pump successfully responds and turns ON and OFF when using the pump terminal software provided by the company.
The C++ Code is:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Define the pins for RX and TX
#define RX_PIN 2
#define TX_PIN 3

SoftwareSerial pumpSerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);

void setup() {
  // Initialize hardware serial for debugging
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect
  }

  // Initialize software serial for pump communication
  pumpSerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Arduino ready to communicate with syringe pump.");
}

void loop() {
  // Command to send
  String command = "run\r\n";

  // Send the command
  Serial.print("Sending command: ");
  Serial.print(command);
  pumpSerial.print(command);

  // Wait for 1 second
  delay(1000);

  // Read and print the response
  String response = "";
  while (pumpSerial.available() > 0) {
    char inChar = (char)pumpSerial.read();
    response += inChar;
  }

  // Print the response if not empty
  if (response != "") {
    Serial.print("Response received: ");
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.println("No response received.");
  }

  // Wait before sending the next command (adjust as needed)
  delay(5000);
}

The Python Code provided by the company is attached in the picture

The setup diagram is attached as well

I encountered issues ... what does that mean?  ... what actually happened?

please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

You did not configure the serial port with 7 databits, odd parity and 2 stopbits as the python script does.
